# Difference between `*p=&` and `p=&`

Tags: c, pointers, diagram, memory-address, dereference

I was given this question as an exercise, but I can't figure out what to do once I get to `fp0 = &hundred;`. Could someone please help me?

> Work your way through the code fragments at pointex.c. What would be printed?
>
> With some of the later exercises draw boxes representing the variables 
>   and arrows representing the pointers.

```
//code fragment g
float ten = 10.0F;
float hundred = 100.0F;
float * fp0 = &ten, * fp1 = &hundred;
fp1 = fp0;
fp0 = &hundred;
*fp1 = *fp0;
printf("ten/hundred = %f\n", ten/hundred);
```

Comment: Did you go through any C tutorial before taking the exercise? Even then there's hint in the question `arrows representing the pointers.`

Comment: What stops someone actually compiling this up and testing it? Why is it even a question?

Comment: Note that the `*` means one thing in a declaration (the variable is a pointer) and another when used as a dereference operator.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from this line:

```
float * fp0 = &ten, * fp1 = &hundred;
```

At this point, `fp0` points to the address of `ten`, so if it were dereferenced like `*fp0` it would return `10.0F`. Likewise `*fp1` would return `100.0F`.
After this line:

```
fp1 = fp0;
```

`fp1` points to the address of `ten`, since its value is now the value of `fp0`, which is just an address pointing to the memory location where the `ten` variable is stored. **Pointers are just addresses**. Dereferencing one returns the value of whatever is stored at the particular address the pointer is pointing to. Then we have this line:

```
fp0 = &hundred;
```

Now `fp0` holds the address of the `hundred` variable, so dereferencing it would return `100.00F`. This next part might be a little tricky:

```
*fp1 = *fp0;
```

By dereferencing `fp1`, we are actually going to the address that `fp1` points to and overwriting the value that was previously stored there (`10.0F`) with the value stored in the address that `fp0` points to (`100.0F`). Thus, the output of the following:

```
printf("ten/hundred = %f\n", ten/hundred);
```

will be "ten/hundred = 1.000000, since we're dividing 100.0F by 100.0F.

Answer (score 0):

Line by line interpretation of the code. Consider `[]` indicates address.

```
float ten = 10.0F;
float hundred = 100.0F;

float * fp0 = &ten, * fp1 = &hundred;

//fp0 --> [10.0F]
//fp1 --> [100.0F]

fp1 = fp0;

//fp1 --> [10.0F]

fp0 = &hundred;

//fp0 --> [100.0F] . fp0 get the address of variable hundred. 
//That means fp0 can change the value stored by variable hundred.

*fp1 = *fp0;  // the value stored at the address `fp1` takes the value stored at the address `fp0`

// [10.0F] --> [100.0F] . Address that was storing 10.0f will now store 100.0f
// So,  ten = 100.0F and hundred = 100.0F

printf("ten/hundred = %f\n", ten/hundred); //prints 1.00000
```